# Вывод строки с тегами через Jquery на Android

Tags: jquery, android, html

```
  text.append("- Plantenbakken H</br>- Tuinafscherming H</br>- Borders H</br>- Losliggend afval </br>H en NH</br>- Tuinmeubelen H")
```

Этой строкой я вывожу строку, но она выводится без отступов и тегов в строке тоже нету 
                Результат таков:

```
 Plantenbakken H- Tuinafscherming H- Borders H- Losliggend afval H en NH- Tuinmeubelen H
```

а должен быть

Plantenbakken H

-Tuinafscherming H

-Borders H

-Losliggend afval H en NH

-Tuinmeubelen H

Comment: это фонеГапом разрабатываешь?

Comment: Сначала тестируйте в chrome (не помешает проверить в safari для iphone, пригодится, да). Потом уже на девайсе(эмуляторе), где дебаг осложнен.

Comment: в браузерах все ое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`</br>` замените на `<br/>`